# Elegantly generate result array in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have my X and Y numpy arrays:

```
X = np.array([0,1,2,3])
Y = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

And my function which maps x,y values to Z points:

```
def z(x,y):
    return x+y
```

I wish to produce the obvious thing required for a 3D plot: the 2-dimensional numpy array for the corresponding Z-values. I believe it should look like:

```
Z = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [1, 2, 3, 4],
              [2, 3, 4, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

I can do this in several lines, but I'm looking for the briefest most elegant piece of code.

Comment: `X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y); z = X+Y`.

Comment: That's the one:)

Answer (score 2):

For a function that is `array` aware it is more economical to use an open grid:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> X = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>> Y = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>>> 
>>> def z(x,y):
...     return x+y
... 
>>> XX, YY = np.ix_(X, Y)
>>> XX, YY
(array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3]]))
>>> z(XX, YY)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

If your grid axes are ranges you can directly create the grid using `np.ogrid`

```
>>> XX, YY = np.ogrid[:4, :4]
>>> XX, YY
(array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3]]))
```

If the function is not `array` aware you can make it so using `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...    if x > y:
...        return x
...    else:
...        return -x
... 
>>> np.vectorize(f)(*np.ogrid[-3:4, -3:4])
array([[ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [-2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [-1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -2, -2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3, -3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One very short way to achieve what you want is to produce a `meshgrid` from your coordinates:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = X+Y
```

or more general:

```
z = f(X,Y)
```

or even in one line:

```
z = f(*np.meshgrid(x,y))
```

**EDIT**:

If your function also may return a constant, you have to somehow infer the dimensions that the result should have. If you want to continue using `meshgrids` one very simple way would be re-write your function in this way:

```
def f(x,y):
   return x*0+y*0+a
```

where `a` would be your constant. `numpy` would then take care of the dimensions for you. This is of course a bit weird looking, so instead you could write

```
def f(x,y):
   return np.full(x.shape, a)
```

If you really want to go with functions that work both on scalars and arrays, it's probably best to go with `np.vectorize` as in @PaulPanzer's answer.

Comment: I was quite sure that this kind of question has been asked before somewhere on StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: After playing about with meshgrids, it turns out there is some somewhat surprising behaviour. For example, if the function returns a scalar constant:  def f(x,y): return 1;  then with z=f(x,y)  you do not receive a 2-dimensional array, but it will simply set z to the scalar...

Comment: @JSStuball That's correct. If you don't tell your function what the dimension of the return value should be, it cannot know. Please see the edit to my answer.